# angular html not rendering on subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code executing on login button click:

```
login() {
console.log('inside login');
this.childComponent.refreshFromParent();  //subscribe greeting
this.app.authenticate(this.credentials, () => { //subjectGreeting.next()
```

the this.childComponent is another component which contains the method refreshFromParent()

```
  refreshFromParent(): void{
    console.log('home component refresh from parent'); 
    this.subscriptionGreeting = this.app.resGreeting.subscribe(r => {
      console.log('inside greeting subscription');
      console.log(r);
      console.log(typeof r);
      console.log(typeof this.greeting);
      if(r){
        this.greeting.id = r.id;
        this.greeting.content = r.content;
        //console.log(r);
        //console.log(this.greeting);
      }
    });
  
  }
```

as can be seen, the refreshFromParent() method is being called before authenticate() method, therefore, subscription is being done before subject.next().

following is the code for authenticate:

```
  authenticate(credentials, callback) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization : 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.username + ':' + credentials.password)
    });

    return this.http.get<Greeting>('http://localhost:8080/user', {headers},).subscribe(response => {
        console.log('Inside app service authenticate');
        if (response) {
            this.authenticated = true;
            console.log(response);
            this.subjectGreeting.next(response);
            this.subjectAuthenticated.next(true);
        } else {
            this.authenticated = false;
            this.subjectAuthenticated.next(false);
        }
        callback();
    });

  }
```

finally, the html of child component which displays a greeting if the object id is not empty string is as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="greeting.id != ''">
    <p> The ID is {{ greeting.id }}</p>
    <p>The content is {{ greeting.content }}</p>
    <p>{{greeting}}</p>
```

however, nothing is being rendered, meaning that greeting.id is empty string.
below is my console log:
[image]

EDIT1:
following is the html page snapshot from browser:
[image]

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is in your this code block. I have update, please make use of this:

```
refreshFromParent(): void{
    console.log('home component refresh from parent'); 
    this.subscriptionGreeting = this.app.resGreeting.subscribe(r => {
      console.log('inside greeting subscription');
      console.log(r);
      console.log(typeof r);
      console.log(typeof this.greeting);
      if(r){
        this.greeting = { ...r };        
        //console.log(r);
        //console.log(this.greeting);
      }
    });
  
  }
```

Comment: tried the above, still not rendering. have updated the question to include snapshot of html page

Comment: @ZeeshanArif can you provide some stackblitz link as that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the condition in your view:

instead of `<div *ngIf="greeting.id != ''">`
try `<div *ngIf="greeting?.id != ''">`
 or `<div *ngIf="(greeting | async)?.id != ''">`